# How to get weather from location usinf openweathermap

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to get the weather from the location.The location is fetched correctly but weather info is not obtained.Please help me solve this

```
getWeatherData("api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=\(city)")
func getWeatherData (urlString:String)
{
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data,response,error) in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.setWeatherData(data!)
        }
    }
}
func setWeatherData(weatherData:NSData)
{
    let json = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(weatherData, options: []) as! NSDictionary

    if let main = json["main"] as? NSDictionary{
        if let temp = main["temp"] as? Double{
            weather = String(format: "%.1f", temp)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not clear please tell what you mean by info not obtained . .  Nil or Empty ?

Comment: Nothing is being saved to weather variable
getWeatherData("api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=\(city)")
Is there anything wrong with the url?

Comment: 1- The URL is incomplete (lacks the prefix). 2- I don't see where you set your API key either. 3- It looks like you forgot to call `resume()` on your task.